# Use Astrisk mark in sql query with like operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a issue with sql query.

This is the query I used to search the result

```
SELECT * FROM wp_wp_campaigns 
WHERE `campaign_status`='1' 
AND `campaign_type`='o' 
AND `campaign_name_decoded` LIKE '%Deep%' 
    OR `campaign_name_decoded` LIKE '%Deep' 
    OR `campaign_name_decoded` LIKE 'Deep%' 
    OR `campaign_name_decoded` LIKE 'Deep_' 
    OR `campaign_name_decoded` LIKE '_Deep' 
    OR `campaign_name_decoded` LIKE '_Deep_' 
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It works perfect when used with only text.

But does not return any value when input value is like **Deep***

Any help in this is highly appriciated.

Comment: I don't believe you.  The logic should return rows in that case.  One possibility is that the values are not exactly what you think they are.

Comment: Why the SQL Server tag? And yeah, `*` isn't a wildcard for `LIKE` so unless the string is equal to `'Deep*'`, there's no match.

Comment: The first wildcard search should match all of the strings below, so those are unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

This does not directly answers your question.  But if you want the filtering on `campaign_status` and `campaign_type` and then on the `campaign_name_decoded`, then this is sufficient:

```
WHERE campaign_status = '1' AND 
      campaign_type = 'o' AND
      campaign_name_decoded` LIKE '%Deep%'
```

The `%` wildcard matches zero or more characters, so is should be doing what you want.

That said, if some campaign names are not matching, that is because you have invalid (unexpected?) characters in either the data column or the comparison.